# Fatiando String e guardando as fatias em uma Lista PYTHON

Tags: python, lista

Olá, gostaria de entender um pouco mais sobre **strings** em **PYTHON**.
Estou desenvolvendo um programa, que consiste em:

Pegar uma STRING

Separar a STRING de 3 em 3 caracteres

E guardar cada parte em uma LISTA

**EX:**

`nome = "guilherme"`

`lista = ["gui","lhe","rme"]`

Comment: Existe alguma maneira de fazer algo parecido ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar fatiamento para acessar fatias de um array (ou string). 
`nome[0:3]` retorna "gui"
`nome[3:6]` retorna "lhe"
E assim por diante.

```
nome = "guilherme"
lista = [nome[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(nome), 3)]
```

Comment: Obrigado, me ajudou muito